# Getting apps-script Service unavailable: Spreadsheets on Gmail accounts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api, google-apps-script-addon

I'm having a problem with regular users of Gmail when using my google spreadsheet add-on. When I load the plugin, so I understand you have FULL permissions, it raise the following error when running this part of code:

```
var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi(); // Same variations.

var result = ui.prompt(
    'Register now',
    'Enter your e-mail:',
    ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);

[...]
```

*Error*

`Service unavailable: Spreadsheets`

The funny part is this just happens with Gmail accounts, not with GSuite users.
I have the permissions:

```
Project OAuth Scopes
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/documents
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.container.ui
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/forms
```

Any idea about this behavior? It has been working for long time and one day suddenly stops working.

Thanks!

Comment: I cannot replicate the issue, for me it works well with any account. Make sure the sharing permissions of the Spreadsheet and the Script are exactly the same. Also, try opening the console (Cntrl+Shift+i) and replicate the error to see what the issue is.

Comment: Does this issue still persist?